# Using varargs from Scala

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out how to do the following:

```
def foo(msf: String, o: Any, os: Any*) = {
    println( String.format(msf, o :: List(os:_*)) )
}
```

There's a reason why I have to declare the method with an `o` and an `os` `Seq` separately. Basically, I end up with the format method called with a single object parameter (of type `List` ). Attempting:

```
def foo(msf: String, o: Any, os: Any*) = {
    println( String.format(msf, (o :: List(os:_*))).toArray )
}
```

Gives me the type error:

> found: Array[Any]
>
> required Seq[java.lang.Object]

I've tried casting, which compiles but fails for pretty much the same reason as the first example. When I try

```
println(String.format(msg, (o :: List(os:_*)) :_* ))
```

this fails to compile with implicit conversion ambiguity (`any2ArrowAssoc` and `any2stringadd`)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
def foo(msf: String, o: AnyRef, os: AnyRef*) = 
  println( String.format(msf, (o :: os.toList).toArray : _* ))
```

Comment: It compiles but falls over at runtime: 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.$colon$colon cannot be cast to scala.runtime.BoxedObjectArray
 at scala.runtime.RichString.format(RichString.scala:242)

Comment: Also, where does toList come from?

Comment: Fixed, it works now. I'm filing a bug report - Scala shouldn't have ClassCastExceptions except when you have used asInstanceOf.  

toList is a method on Iterable[A]

Comment: Apparently it's been fixed in the 2.8 branch http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/1360

Comment: Why was toArray necessary, though? List is a valid input to : _*.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala for explanation

Answer (score 13):

```
def foo(msf: String, o: AnyRef, os: AnyRef*) =
  println( String.format(msf, o :: os.toList : _* ) )
```

or

```
def foo(msf: String, o: AnyRef, os: AnyRef*) =
      println( msf format (o :: os.toList : _* ) )
```

I much prefer the latter, though it has no locale* support.

- Scala 2.8 does have locale support with RichString's format.

Comment: Using the RichString format method is what I opted for in the end