# Twitter4j muliple keywords querying using scala

Tags: scala, twitter4j

I'm trying to get the equivalent of the following java code in scala for querying multiple keywords in twitter4j application

```
// In java
FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();

String[] itemsToTrack = {"python", "java", "php"};

filterQuery.track(itemsToTrack);

twitterStream.filter(filterQuery);

// In scala I have written
val itemsToTrack = Array("python", "java", "php")
val filterQuery = new FilterQuery()
filterQuery.track(itemsToTrack)
```

Above line gives error as it is expecting a string rather than a string array.

So my question is what if the equivalent of java code above using scala for querying multiple keywords in scala.

NOTE - > I'm new in scala

Answer (score 0):

`filterQuery.track` is a Java function with a variable number of arguments. Its definition is:

```
public FilterQuery track(java.lang.String... track)
```

To call such a method from Scala, you would normally use this syntax:

```
filterQuery.track("java", "python", "scala")
```

If the arguments are already in an Array or another kind of sequence, you can use:

```
filterQuery.track(itemsToTrack:_*)
```

See also: [Scala: pass Seq to var-args functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832061/scala-pass-seq-to-var-args-functions)