# Parameterise spark partition by clause

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to insert a `DataFrame` in na existing Hive partitioned table.

I would like to parameterize by the partition columns but my current approach is not working:

```
var partitioncolumn="\"deletion_flag\",\"date_feed\""
df.repartition(37).write.
  mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
  partitionBy(partitioncolumn).
  insertInto("db.table_name")
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`partitionBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@partitionBy(colNames:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[T]) takes a variable number of arguments (namely, `String`s).

```
def partitionBy(colNames: String*): DataFrameWriter[T]
//                              ^ this stands for variadic arguments
```

In Scala, you can pass postfix a sequence with `: _*` to pass it as an argument list.

So you could do something like the following:

```
var partitioncolumn= Seq("deletion_flag", "date_feed")
df.repartition(37).write.
  mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
  partitionBy(partitioncolumn: _*).
  insertInto("db.table_name")
```

Passing a sequence as variadic arguments is also described in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832061/scala-pass-seq-to-var-args-functions).

Answer (score 3):

As `partitionBy` is defined with variadic arguments:

```
def partitionBy(colNames: String*): DataFrameWriter[T]
```

It should be:

```
var partitioncolumn= Seq("deletion_flag", "date_feed")
df.repartition(37).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).partitionBy(
   partitioncolumn: _*
).insertInto("db.table_name")
```

where you provide expanded list of column names.

Comment: I have same answer from both the persons so I can only choose one is that ok if I take stefanobaghino as answer