# Scalamock : How to specify arbitrary sequence of tuples

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, scalamock

I am trying to create a mock for Play's WSClient like this:

```scala
  def mockGet[A](url : String, method : String, headers : Seq[(String, String)], timeout : Duration)(
    response: Future[AhcWSResponse]
  ) =
    (mockWsClient
      .url(_ : String)
        .withMethod(_ : String)
        .withHttpHeaders(_: (String, String)*)
        .withRequestTimeout(_ : Duration)
        .stream())
      .expects(url, method, headers, timeout)
      .returning(response)
```

The problem is the `withHttpHeaders` - this actually takes (String, String)* but when I specify that type as above I get a compiler error like this:

```scala
[error]  found   : Seq[(String, String)]
[error]  required: (String, String)
[error]       .withHttpHeaders(_: Seq[(String, String)])
```

What type do I need to specify for this method because (String, String) is not correct. The actual real definition of this method is:

```scala
  override def withHttpHeaders(headers: (String, String)*): Self
```

***UPDATE***

I tried this after @Mario's suggestion:

```scala
  def mockGet[A](url: String, method: String, headers: Seq[(String, String)], timeout: Duration)(
    response: (String, String, Duration) => Future[ws.WSResponse]
  ) =
    (
      (
        xs: Seq[(String, String)]
      ) =>
        mockWsClient
          .url(_: String)
          .withMethod(_: String)
          .withRequestTimeout(_: Duration)
          .withHttpHeaders(xs: _*)
          .stream()
      )
      .expects(headers)
      .returning(response)
```

but this crashes the compiler with:

```scala
[error] value x$1
```

Comment: This will work right? `.withHttpHeaders(headers: _*)`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832061/scala-pass-seq-to-var-args-functions

Comment: Example:
`def k(s: (String, String)*) = s
val k1 = Seq[(String, String)](("a","b"), ("b", "c"))
k(k1:_*)`

Comment: No, it's the setting up of the mock

Comment: You can try to pass `headers: _*` in expects right?

Comment: only answer if you know how to use scalamock

Answer (score 1):

The key is to understand how the *anonymous function placeholder parameter* syntax works. For example, given

```
def f(i: Int*) = ???
```

then

```
f(_: Int)
```

expands to

```
(i: Int) => f(i)
```

Hence try

```
def mockGet(headers : Seq[(String, String)) =
  ((xs: Seq[(String, String)]) => mockWsClient.withHttpHeaders(xs: _*)).expects(headers)
```

Here is a simplified example

```
trait Zar {
  def f(i: Int*) = i
}

class ScalamockVarargsSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with MockFactory {
  "Varargs" should "be mockable" in {
    val zar = mock[Zar]
    ((xs: Seq[Int]) => zar.f(xs: _*)).expects(Seq(1,2))
    zar.f(1,2)
  }
}
```

In your particular case there are multiple anonymous function placeholder parameters, so try expanding them all, for example

```
def mockGet(url: String, headers : Seq[(String, String)) =
  ((u: String, xs: Seq[(String, String)]) => mockWsClient.url(u).withHttpHeaders(xs: _*))
    .expects(url, headers)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of headers param here?

Comment: I tried you suggestion but modified it to account of all the parameters, but it resulted in a compiler crash. Please see my update to my post. Any idea why that is happening? I think we are nearly there

Comment: Yes I did exactly that, but the code does not compile. Have you tried to compile it?

Comment: Try to compile this:
  def mockGet(url: String, headers: Seq[(String, String)]) =
    ((u: String, xs: Seq[(String, String)]) => mockWsClient.url(u).withHttpHeaders(xs: _*))
      .expects(url, headers)

Comment: This results in: [error] Error while emitting FooSpec.scala
[error] value u