# How do I pass args into custom method I've written in Play 2?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I wrote a method in my Play Framework 2 scala template to generate date/time inputs.  I can't figure out how to pass html args like `_label` into it though.

```
@dateField(field: Field, timeName: String)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang) = {
    @input(field, '_showConstraints -> false) { (id, name, value, args) =>
        <input type="text" value="@value" name="@name" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
        <input type="text" value='@eventForm(timeName).value()' name="@timeName" />
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to call this to generate a field with no label:

```
@dateField(eventForm("event.endDate"), "event.endTime", '_label -> "")
```

What do I need to do for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define a vargs field. In Scala, this is denoted by an asterisk. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008783/using-varargs-from-scala) for more details.

Your code would then look like this:

```
@dateField(field: Field, timeName: String, more: (Symbol, Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang:  play.api.i18n.Lang) = {
  @input(field, ('_showConstraints -> false :: more.toList) : _*) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input type="text" value="" name="@name" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error at `:: more...` Here is the message: `type mismatch; found : List[(Symbol, Any)] required: (Symbol, Any) Note: implicit method implicitFieldConstructor is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type'`

Comment: Really? For me this works. Did you copy-paste it? Your error suggests that the last part (`: _*`) is missing.