# Passing elements of a List as parameters to a function with variable arguments

Tags: function, scala

I have a function called `or` for example, which is defined as;

```
or(filters: FilterDefinition*)
```

And then I have a list:

```
List(X, Y, Z)
```

What I now need to do is call `or` like

```
or(func(X), func(Y), func(Z))
```

And as expected the length of the list may change.

What's the best way to do this in Scala?

Comment: Not exactly the same question but it gives the `: _*` notation which is the key to the answer (assuming you can just `list.map(func)`!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008783

Comment: If we pass the whole list elements and process all of them in the called function, then it can also be done by just passing the list to the function and the function can iterate thru the elements, without the need for special syntax of :_* ,right? Or I may be wrong, is there any good reason for this usage?

Comment: @user3366706 that would be the more traditional approach to do things, yes. For me this came in incredibly handy when dealing with a DSL that expected a generated query as the function argument – with variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Take a look at this example, I will define a function printme that takes vargs of type String

```
def printme(s: String*) = s.foreach(println)


scala> printme(List("a","b","c"))

<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[String]
 required: String
              printme(List(a,b,c))
```

What you really need to un-pack the list into arguments with the `:_*` operator

```
scala> val mylist = List("1","2","3")
scala> printme(mylist:_*)
1
2
3
```

Comment: It also work with class: `case class ExampleClass (d: Double*)`