# Scala: expanding Array of arguments into List gives error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am attempting to pass a list of parameters to a function.

```
scala> val a = Array("col1", "col2")
a: Array[String] = Array(col1, col2)
```

I'm trying to use the `:_*` notation, but it's not working: and I cannot for the life of me work out why!

```
val edges = all_edges.select(a:_*)
<console>:27: error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
(col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
(cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
cannot be applied to (String)
```

This, however, does work:
`val edges = all_edges.select("col1", "col2")`

Not sure if it is relevant, but all_edges is a spark dataframe which I am attempting to only keep columns by specifying them in a list.

```
 scala> all_edges
 res4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Any ideas? I've been trying to work out the syntax from eg. [Passing elements of a List as parameters to a function with variable arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815576/passing-elements-of-a-list-as-parameters-to-a-function-with-variable-arguments) but don't seem to be getting far

Edit: Just found [How to "negative select" columns in spark's dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434886/how-to-negative-select-columns-in-sparks-dataframe) - but I am confused as to why the syntax `twocol.select(selectedCols.head, selectedCols.tail: _*)` is necessary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to pass strings, the signature of the function indicates that you have to pass at least one:

```
(col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

So you have to single out the first argument of your list : Spark cannot from the type of a `Traversable` alone determine that it is not empty.

```
val edges = all_edges.select(a.head, a.tail: _*)
```

Now, that's the dirty version of it. If you want to do this rigorously, you should check the list is not empty yourself:

```
val edges = a.headOption.map( (fst) => all_edges.select(fst, a.drop(1))
```

Comment: Thanks - as a general scala question - if the function signature is (col: String,cols: String*), why does only having String still work (there don't seem to be any other overloads? eg. `all_edges.select("col1")?`

Comment: Because an empty sequence is still a sequence, so that it's acceptable to "interpret" (adapt) `all_edges.select("col1")` as `all_edges.select("col1", Seq(): _*)`