# Check if all keys are present in Map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Let there is a map `config: Map[String, String]`.

And there are several keys: `"foo", "bar", ...`

I need to make sure that all keys are present in `config`. And if they are present, I need to call a function with values for these keys in the `config` map:

```
fun(config("foo"), config("bar"), config(...), ...)
```

The following is a solution:

```
val res = Option.when(config.contains("foo") & config.contains("bar") & config.contains(...) & ...)
    ( fun(config("foo"), config("bar"), config(...), ...) )
```

Or maybe:

```
val set = Set("foo", "bar", ...)
val res = Option.when(config.view.filterKeys(set).size == set.size)
    ( fun(config("foo"), config("bar"), config(...), ...) )
```

Both approaches look ugly and ineffective. Is there more concise way to implement the same behavior?

Comment: what is the signature of your function?

Comment: Something like `fun(foo: String, bar: String, one: String, two: String, three: String)`, where all params `foo, bar, one, two, three` extract from `config` map

Comment: Is the set of keys dynamic or static?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - static

Answer (score 2):

Since the set of keys is static, you do not need to do anything too complex.
You just need to attempt to get each key and if all are in call the function and wrap the result in a **Some**, if not then return a **None**.

```
for {
  value1 <- config.get("key1")
  // ...
  valueN <- config.get("keyN")
} yield fun(value1, ..., valueN)
```

If you have **cats**, you can do it like.

```
(
  config.get("key1"),
  // ...
  config.get("keyN")
).mapN(fun(_).tupled)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider `forall` in combination with `contains`

```
val requiredKeys = List("foo", "bar")

if (requiredKeys forall config.contains) {
  // work with config
} else {
  // handler error
}
```

or based on [Tom Crockett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3622917/5205022) consider `keySet` approach

```
val requiredKeys = Set("foo", "bar")

if (requiredKeys subsetOf config.keySet) {
  // work with config
} else {
  // handler error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have your keys as ("foo", "bar", ...).map(config) returns the values, right? then if it contains a None, then not all keys are found. I would start to think along this idea.

[Passing elements of a List as parameters to a function with variable arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815576/passing-elements-of-a-list-as-parameters-to-a-function-with-variable-arguments) helps here, so val args = list.map(config);
then the condition to check if all values are present, and finally 
fun(args:_*).

how about that?

Answer (score 0):

This is using cats, a very common FP library:

```
import cats.implicits._

def fun(a: String, b: String, c: String): MyConfigClass = ???

val parsedOpt: Option[MyConfigClass] = 
  (config.get("a"), config.get("b"), config.get("c"))
  .mapN(fun)
```

The `mapN` method does what you want, it will extact all values if they exist and provide them to fun. For the curious, it relies on the fact that `Option` is an `Applicative`.

To show its power, you could also get back a list of missing keys, to know where the issue was:

```
import cats.data._
def getConfig(key: String): Either[NonEmptyList[String], String] =
config.get(key).toRightNel(s"Key $key not found")

val parsedValidated: Either[NonEmptyList[String], MyConfigClass] =
  (getConfig("a"), getConfig("b"), getConfig("c"))
 .parMapN(fun)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a `flatMap` way:

```
config.get("key1").flatMap(key1 =>
config.get("key2").flatMap(key2 =>
...
config.get("keyN").flatMap(keyN =>
fun(key1, key2, ..., keyN)
))...)
```

Comment: Yes, if `fun()` returns `Option`. Otherwise use `.map()` for `keyN`, which is exactly what @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez posted in his answer (via `for` comprehension).