# how to convert List(String,String) to ListMap[String,String]?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a list of type `List(String,String)` and I wanted to convert it to map. When I used `toMap` method I found that it does not preservers the order of data that is there in the List. However my goal is to convert the list to Map by keeping the order of the data same as of List. I learned that `ListMap` preserves the insertion order(but it is immutable) so I can use the LinkedHashMap with map function to insert the data sequentially into `LinkedHashMap` but that means I need to iterate over all the elements which is pain. Can anyone please suggest me a better approach?
Thanks

Comment: "my goal is to convert the list to Map by keeping the order of the data same as of List". Maps don't work like that

Comment: " I learned that ListMap preserves the insertion order" How did you learn that? There's nothing in the documentation.

Comment: I got to know from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835743/scala-map-implementation-keeping-entries-in-insertion-order

Comment: Apparently the answers there tell you to use LinkedHashMap, why not give it a try.

Comment: @n.m. I am trying both and learning about the performance too of both the collections.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should do it :

```
val listMap = ListMap(list : _*)
```

Comment: Thanks @C4stor for your comment, it worked. I am new to scala and a small explanation on the annotation would help a lot in understanding in depth.

Comment: [ListMap#apply](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.ListMap$@apply[A,B](elems:(A,B)*):CC[A,B]) accepts tuple varargs. By calling `: _*`, list's elements are applied in a varargs fashion, as I understand. Perhaps this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinmeredith/b4b3e35bf7bfadce253a8d74aef1c7ef) will help. See, also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008783/using-varargs-from-scala for more info.

Comment: @KevinMeredith got it right. I think a more relevant question to understand : _* is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala which have, hopefully, all information you need :)

Comment: "colon underscore star" works nice, but my favorite is `mylist.to(ListMap)` (Scala >=2.13) mentioned by @Jasper-M

Comment: Sure, but scala 2.13 was released more than 2 years after this question was asked, so there's that ^^

Answer (score 4):

In Scala 2.13 or later:

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

scala> val list = List((1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,0))
list: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,0))

scala> list.to(ListMap)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[Int,Int] = ListMap(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6, 7 -> 8, 9 -> 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a ListMap. They are extremely imperformant. Since they are structured as lists they have linear lookup performance (https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)

I'd advise instanciating a mutable LinkedHashmap and then assigning it to a val defined as a collections.Map. The collection.Map interface doesn't expose mutable methods so the map is immutable to any entity accessing it.