# How to convert a Seq[User] so that I can pass it into A* param?

Tags: scala

I have a sequence of Users in a collection

```
val users: Seq[User]
```

And I want to pass it into the Queue.enqueue method that takes:

```
def enqueue(elems : A*)
```

I can foreach on my collection but I am sure there is a way to convert it right?

Also, what is A* called again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using varargs from Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008783/using-varargs-from-scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A*` is a varargs type. To pass a collection to such a function, you can use the special vararg-expansion syntax, like this:

```
queue.enqueue(seq: _*) // If queue is of type Queue[User].
```

You can use this notation only if your collection is a `Seq`, or if it can be implicitly converted to a `Seq`.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as `A` is a type parameter and is compatible (as for type constraints/variance) with `User`:

```
enqueue(users: _*)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the queue is mutable, you can use `enqueue` as pointed out by other answers 
or use `++=`

```
scala> val mQueue = scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int](1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
mQueue: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val aSeq = Seq[Int](6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
aSeq: Seq[Int] = List(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> mQueue ++= aSeq
res26: mQueue.type = Queue(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

If the queue is immutable, you have to use `enqueue` as following:

```
scala> val imQueue = scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int](1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
imQueue: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> imQueue.enqueue(aSeq.toList)
res32: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

In case of immutable, as the name suggests, `imQueue` is not updated, instead 
another immutable queue is returned.

```
scala> imQueue
res33: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // still original values
```